# phpmailer не работает,Помогите

Tags: php, сервер, email, backend, phpmailer

> Fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException: Could not execute:
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail in
>   W:\domains\Arams-Luggage.loc\layouts\default\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php:684
>   Stack trace: #0
>   W:\domains\Arams-Luggage.loc\layouts\default\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(628):
>   PHPMailer->SendmailSend('Date: Wed, 16 O...', '--b1_6e7019eceb...') #1
>   W:\domains\Arams-Luggage.loc\layouts\default\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(575):
>   PHPMailer->PostSend() #2
>   W:\domains\Arams-Luggage.loc\layouts\default\pages\contact.php(36):
>   PHPMailer->Send() #3 W:\domains\Arams-Luggage.loc\index.php(441):
>   require_once('W:\domains\Aram...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   W:\domains\Arams-Luggage.loc\layouts\default\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php
>   on line 684

Comment: Посмотрите в `phpinfo()` sendmail_path и убедитесь что он корректный. Так же, есть вариант что сервер не поддерживает sendmail, узнайте об этом у хост провайдера

Comment: я на локальном пробуя сейчас.
sendmail_path   w:\modules\sendmail\sendmail.exe -local

Comment: Ну вот и ответ на ваш вопрос.. У вас `sendmail_path  == w:\modules\sendmail\sendmail.exe`, тогда как в class.phpmailer.php `sendmail_path  ==   /usr/sbin/sendmail`. Поменяйте путь в классе на свой, или отключите проверку isSendmail()

Comment: Спасибо. я поменял.патом откл. но  теперь после отправки формы никаких ошибок не выдает но и не отправляет письмо на почту. даже проверку после него не делает который должен был ошибку напечатать на экране при ошибку